# See scripts through http GET requests

Tags: security, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

Everyone!!
I perform penetration test to some site with ZAP tool and i found that i can see by means GET request the text from jquery library, something like this:

```
    http://bad.bad.com/ca/resources/scripts;jsessionid=555555555555555FFFFFFDD2222222
    /libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

Is it vulnerability for site?Should it be prohibited by developers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess no. Pentesters got nothing to do with that

Comment: .Thank you!! I am newbie in this topic.It seems to me that site shouldn't show this, because it can be a weak point in security. Can you give me some information or more examples on this issue?